# How to navigate from one page to another in UWP using react native?

Tags: react-native, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am new to react native with UWP, I installed react native windows and initialized a new project. The project contains the IOS, Android and windows folder. In the windows folder, it has a visual studio solution. When I run the App it opened me to a welcome screen. Now I want to create 2 page in UWP and navigate from one to another. I searched for it but I couldn't find any docs or tutorials. If someone knows where to find a tutorial on this plz help me.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution for this?..

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to Develop the react-native app for Android,iOS and windows UWP also. I tried with react-navigation versions 3x and 4x. But its not working, because of react-native-gesture-handler. So i downgrade my react-navigation version as 2.18.3 in react-native version 0.59.10. Now its working fine for me. For react-navigation below 3x no need react-native-gesture-handler.

Answer (score -1):

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation

You can use the same navigation provided by React-Native official docs. Or else you can use react-navigation package.